# How to run Eclipse plugin in the Wind River Workbench?

Tags: eclipse, wind-river-workbench

I have developed an plugin in Eclipse. The version is 3.4.1. The plugin is installed in Wind River Workbench 3.2. The version of Eclipse Platform is 3.5.1.The plugin is not work. My question is the phenomenon is affected by version of Eclipse?

Comment: The version of Eclipse Platform is 3.5.1 in  Wind River Workbench 3.2

Comment: Without more detail on what's not working, it's hard to give a proper answer. What's the plug-in supposed to do that it's not doing?

Comment: The error is "Problems opening perspective 'cn.com.sca.ui.scaPerspective' ".